# Checkbox setChecked() through a layout inflater

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a game in android studio and I ran into a problem when designing the settings tab:

I have a settings XML file that I access through the java code from the main menu screen, and I want to set the checkboxes according to a sharedpreferences file.

The thing is that while the actual preferences are updated, whenever I call `setChecked()` it doesn't do anything.

what I am trying to is:

```
    final LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View settingsView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null);
    CheckBox test = settingsView.findViewById(R.id.testCheck);
    test.setChecked(true); // not really doing anything
```

Ty for all the help :)

Comment: Layouts are just blueprints. They do not store any dynamic state information. Each time a layout is inflated, `LayoutInflater` creates brand new instances of the `View`s which are unrelated to any other instances created from that same layout. Checking that box in `settingsView` there will have no effect on the `View`s in your settings `Activity`. Instead, simply set your `Checkbox`es in your settings `Activity` from `SharedPreferences`, in `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Answer (score -1):

Try like below.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
CheckBox test = settingsView.findViewById(R.id.testCheck);
test.post(new Runnable() {
@override
public void run() {
   test.setChecked(true);
}});
```

Comment: no luck with that :/ doing it made the activity take all the space on the screen, and still didn't set the checkboxes

Comment: Are you certain that checkbox element with id "testCheck" is located in the layout "activity_settings"

Comment: yeah, I added the widget to the settings XML file